# Visual Studio 2005, display null terminated char buffers as UTF-8 strings while debugging

Tags: string, visual-studio, debugging, utf-8, visual-studio-2005

Is it possible, using Visual Studio 2005 (and higher) to display a null terminated char buffer as UTF-8 strings while debugging ?

For example, if i have a buffer containing the bytes of the UTF-8 string `"Здравствуйте"`, is there an option to display it as such (when hovering it with the mouse) instead of the ugly ascii equivalent : `"Ð—Ð´Ñ€Ð°Ð²ÑÑ‚Ð²ÑƒÐ¹Ñ‚Ðµ"` ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `s8` format specifier in the debug expression:

[image]

Your version of VS is stone cold old however, not sure if VS2005 supported it yet.

Comment: No it doesn't work with 2005. THanks for the tip anyway.